# How to recover data in crashed ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, mount, data-recovery, crash, grubrescue

I am using ubuntu for past few years along side windows7. recently ubuntu has crashed and showing grub rescue mode. i have again installed ubuntu in other partition. how can i recover my data in lost ubuntu. i have important data in it.
it is in dev/sda5, it is showing in the disk menu as unknown(86 GB), and it is unable to mount. please help in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous Ubuntu installation you have, did you set up anything like LVM, Software RAID, or so? If you open up gparted on the disk, can you see a file system type on sda5?

Comment: i typed the command df -T , then it is not showing sda5. but when i see in the disks menu i can see sda5 as unknown partition.

Comment: Install gpart and gparted (`sudo apt-get install gpart gparted`). Run: `sudo gpart /dev/sda5`. This will scan the partition, trying to guess the partition type. Paste the output here.

Comment: it is just showing Begin scan... for long time. no other output.

Comment: Yes, it will take quite some time, it's analyzing your disk for what partitions it can find. If you're sure that  there are no partition problems, you can skip that step. On the other hand, something bad happened, since the partition  type label disappeared from sda5. Do you remember what file system type you had on that partition?

Comment: no idea. and the system is struck. is there any other way to recover.please recommend .

Comment: I cannot directly come up with a better one than gpart, as things look.  Maybe you'd have more success, with TestDisk, but I haven't used it.  For a guide in using that for partition recovery, see this one: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-data-recovery.html